# How to get a specific value from url params generated by Ransack gem for Ruby on Rails from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ransack

My url looks like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/ads?utf8=✓&q%5Bbrand_eq%5D=ALFA+ROMEO&q%5Bmodel_eq%5D=GTV+%26+Spider&commit=Search
```

(generated by Ransack gem)

I want to receive from it 'model_eq' value, which in this example should look like this:

```
GTV & Spider
```

Is there any painless method to do this from JavaScript (CoffeeScript) in Rails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex to extract data from the URL.

```js
var url = 'http://localhost:3000/ads?utf8=✓&q%5Bbrand_eq%5D=ALFA+ROMEO&q%5Bmodel_eq%5D=GTV+%26+Spider&commit=Search';

var model = (url.match(/model_eq.*?=(.+)&/) || [])[1];
alert(decodeURIComponent(model));
```

The regex will extract the text that is after `model_eq=`.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!